# HashMap override value only if value for particular key is null/empty/"None"

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I am stuck with a HashMap issue. I am trying to copy data from one HashMap to another.

Please excuse my syntax - this is just an example. I also tried looking at other examples but could not find anything for my usecase.

Lets say -

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap1 = {(1, "New Value"), (2, "New Value")}    
HashMap<String, String> finalHashMap = {(1, "None"), (2, "Blah"), (3, "Something else")}
```

This is the original code:

```
hashMap1.forEach(finalHashMap::putIfAbsent);
```

This is final output I want:

```
finalHashMap = {(1, "New Value"), (2, "Blah"), (3, "Something else")}
```

Note: 2 does not get overwritten because its value is not "None"

This works when Null or Empty case but not for None case :(

Can someone help me and modify code to help with "None" case as well?

I can do this traditional way, but trying to see if there is any one liner that I can use for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. For each value in the `hashMap1` that meets your condition in `finalHashMap`, replace it with the value for the same key in `hashMap1`. It's important to first check for a null value so future tests won't throw an NPE.

```
hashMap1.forEach((k, v) -> { String value = finalHashMap.get(k);
    if (value == null || value.equals("None") || value.isEmpty()) {
        finalHashMap.put(k, hashMap1.get(k));
    }
});

System.out.println(finalHashMap);
```

prints

```
{1=New Value, 2=Blah, 3=Something else}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.toMap` and check the collisions:

```java
Map<String, String> merged = 
    Stream.concat(finalHashMap.entrySet().stream(), hashMap1.entrySet().stream())
          .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                         (a, b) -> (a == null || a.isEmpty() || "None".equals(a)) ? b : a));
```